# How to pass account address to truffle deployer?

Tags: contract-development, truffle, dapp-development, truffle-migration, truffle-deployment

How do I pass my account address to the contract constructor while deploying with truffle migration? I want to pass address into `MyAdress` like below.

```
deployer.deploy(MyContract, MyAddress)
```

My contract looks like this

```
address payable public admin;
constructor(address payable _admin) {
        admin = _admin;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the address as a constant in the deployment file:

```
const MyAddress = '0x123...'

deployer.deploy(MyContract, MyAddress)
```

Answer (score 2):

Refer address to truffle config file is more appropriable.

```
module.exports = async function(deployer, network, accounts) {
  const deployerAddress = accounts[0];
  await deployer.deploy(Contract, deployerAddress);
};
```

Comment: There's also a third parameter `accounts` https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/running-migrations.html#available-accounts.

Comment: Thanks @Ismael. I updated example code.

Answer (score 1):

You can also decide to just put in the address
`deployer.deploy(contractName, "addresshere")`